# All subgroups of a finite abelian group

Tags: reference-request, abelian-groups

It is well known that a finite abelian group $G$ (written additively) can be written as
$$
G \simeq \mathbf{Z}_{p_1^{\alpha_1}} \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbf{Z}_{p_k^{\alpha_k}},
$$
for some not necessarily distinct primes $p_1,\ldots,p_k$. Now, given nonnegative integers $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_k$ such that $\beta_i\le \alpha_i$ for each $i$, then
$$
\mathbf{Z}_{p_1^{\beta_1}} \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbf{Z}_{p_k^{\beta_k}}
$$
is (isomophic to) a subgroup of $G$.

**Question:** Is there a name for the finite abelian groups $G$ such that *all and only* subgroups of $G$ are the direct sums above?

---

Edit: I just noticed it is related related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485512/subgroups-of-a-direct-product) and this [other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509322/how-many-subgroups-does-mathbbz-6-times-mathbbz-6-times-mathbbz-6-tim/510460#510460)..

Comment: Don't all finite abelian groups have this property?

Comment: They are those where $p_1,\dots,p_s$ are pairwise distinct. I seem to remember *basic groups*, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! I found *basic subgroup* on Wikipedia, but it does not seem to be the same.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_subgroup

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti It seems I remembered wrongly.

Comment: @egreg No worry, thanks anyway

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti The subgroup $\{(x,x): x \in \mathbb{Z}_p\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, so I'm not sure that's a counterexample. But you want the subgroups to be generated by elements of the form $(0,\ldots, 1, \ldots, 0)$, right? In that case, your counterexample works. But it wasn't clear to me at first that this was what you meant.

Comment: @JoshuaRuiter Right! However, I think you meant $\mathbf{Z}_p \oplus \{0\}$

Answer (score 1):

Haha! These are called (finite) **cyclic** groups. As egreg remarked, it must be the case that no same prime number $p$ occurs more then once, or there would be a subgroup $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^2$ that spoils your property. But then the Chinese remainder theorem applies and your group is cyclic. Conversely any cyclic group is easily seen to have this property, again by the Chinese remainder theorem if you like.