# What is the number of subgroups of $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2 \times \cdots \times C_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, field-theory

I think that counting the number of subgroups of various groups is usually very difficult.  I was wondering about the number of subgroups of $(C_2)^n$.  For example,  there are 5 subgroups of $C_2 \times C_2$ and there are 16 subgroups of $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$.  I found these counts in the corresponding Math World articles.

Is it very difficult to count the subgroups of $(C_2)^n$ ?  Is this sequence in Sloane's OEIS ?  I would be satisfied in just knowing a few more terms or to see some references about how these might be counted.

Comment: Have you heard of $q$-binomial coefficients?  If so, the answer is $\sum_{r=0}^n\,\binom{n}{r}_q$ evaluated at $q=2$.

Comment: Thanks Batominovski,  I am NOT familiar with q-binomial coefficients.  Is there any way to explain them or can the answer be given in another form?  I should have mentioned in my question that a Mathematica code might also help me.

Comment: Well, you can identify a subgroup $C_2^n$ as a vector subspace of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$.  Hence, the number of subgroups of $C_2^n$ is the number of subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$.  There are precisely $\binom{n}{r}_{q=2}$ subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ of dimension $r$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142589/how-to-count-number-of-bases-and-subspaces-of-a-given-dimension-in-a-vector-spac.

Comment: And sure enough, here is the OEIS entry: https://oeis.org/A006116