# How many ways to choose the basis of a space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's consider the space $V = k^n$ for $k = \mathbb{F}_p$ where $p$ is a prime number. How many ways are there to choose the basis of this space?

Comment: This is a standard fact: the answer is $$\prod_{j < n} (p^n-p^j)$$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142589/

Comment: Note that $$\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(p^n-p^j)=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}p^j(p^{n-j}-1)=p^{\binom{n}2}\prod_{j=1}^n(p^j-1)\;,$$ the last form also sometimes being useful.