# Order of sublattice.

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, modular-arithmetic, modular-forms, hecke-algebras

I am reading serre's book A Course in Arithmetic"",
and want to understand the Hecke operator.
Let $\omega_1,\omega_2\in \mathbb{C},$
and $\frac{\omega_1}{\omega_1}\in \mathbb{H},$
where $\mathbb{H}$ stands for upper half plane,
we define a *lattice* in $\mathbb{C}$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
\Gamma:=\mathbb{Z}\omega_1\oplus\mathbb{Z}\omega_2.
\end{align*} 
It is obviously a additive subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$.
Let $\mathcal{R}$ be the set of lattices of $\mathbb{C}$,
and $X_\mathcal{R}$ be the free abelian group generated by $\mathcal{R}$.

Suppose that $T(n):X_\mathcal{R}\longrightarrow X_\mathcal{R}$ is a group homomorphism defined as follow:
\begin{align*}
T(n)\Gamma=\sum_{(\Gamma,\Gamma')=n}\Gamma'.
\end{align*}
In other words, $T(n)$ transforms a lattice to the sum of its sub-lattices of index $n$.

With the notations above,
he said:
[image]
My qusetion:

- why the lattice $\Gamma'$ must contains $n\Gamma$?
- why the number of $\Gamma'$ is equal to the number of subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2$ of order $n$?
- how can we count the number of projective lines over finite fields?

---

Some of ny ideas:

- I sence that it may need "Fundamental theorem on homomorphisms".
- I have known a obvious isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\omega_1\oplus\mathbb{Z}\omega_2\cong\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}.$
  Thus we can just consider the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.

  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your first comment is not very serious: do you know how many books has Serre's written?

Comment: All right, I mean "A Course in Arithmetic".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that as $\Gamma'$ has index $n$ in $\Gamma$, we have that $\Gamma/\Gamma'$ has order $n$ as an abelian group and so for every $\overline{x}\in \Gamma/\Gamma'$, $n\overline{x}=\overline{0}$. This just means that for every $x\in\Gamma$, $nx\in \Gamma'$. In other words,
$$n\Gamma\subseteq \Gamma'\text{.}$$
Once this is clear, note that there is by the isomorphism (or correspondence) theorems (depending in your terminology) a one-to-one correspondence between subgroups of $\Gamma$ containing $n\Gamma$ and subgroups of $\Gamma/n\Gamma$ given by
$$L\leq\Gamma\mapsto L/n\Gamma$$
that preserves the index of the subgroups (by the third isomorphism theorem). In this way, we have that there as many subgroups of index $n$ in $\Gamma$ as subgroups of index $n$ in $\Gamma/n\Gamma$ as every subgroup of index $n$ of $\Gamma$ contains $n\Gamma$.

As you notice, $\Gamma$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$. Hence $\Gamma/n\Gamma$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/n(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})$ which is just $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2$. Hence there are as many subgroups of index $n$ in $\Gamma$ as subgroups of index $n$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2$ which, as $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2$ has order $n^2$, are also the subgroups of order $n$ of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2$.

In conclusion, the essential ingredients in all these arguments have been Lagrange's index theorem for subgroups (and its corollaries) and the isomorphism $\Gamma\cong \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.

For your last question, just notice that it is the same as counting the number of linear planes in a vector space over a finite field. You can found the answer to that question in general in the question ["How to count number of bases and subspaces of a given dimension in a vector space over a finite field?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142589/how-to-count-number-of-bases-and-subspaces-of-a-given-dimension-in-a-vector-spac?noredirect=1&lq=1). However, note that the subgroups of order $p$ of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^2$ correspond to the points of the projective line over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Your answer is great! Thanks very much. $P^1_(F_p)$ has the same elements as the 1-dimensional subspace of $F_p\times F_p$. They are gennerated by $(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),\ldots,(1,p-1),(0,p-1)$ respectively. Right?

Comment: @VerMoriarty That's right!