# number of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I am trying to find number of subgroups of  $\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$ for prime $p$. I got $p^2+p+1$ subgroups of order $p$, but for subgroups of order $p^2$, I cant see how would it be $p^2 + p+1$ subgroups?

Is there any generalised method for $\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$..... and so on.?

Comment: try $p=2$.${}{}{}$

Comment: i was able to verify the formula, but I could just not see how was that obtained. I mean for order $p$, i took the number of $p$ order elements. but$p^2$ group is direct product of groups and I got lost

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient

Answer (score 1):

You can consider this group a vector space over the field $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Your question thus reduces to this question [How to count number of bases and subspaces of a given dimension in a vector space over a finite field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142589/how-to-count-number-of-bases-and-subspaces-of-a-given-dimension-in-a-vector-spac)

Comment: ok. thanks. I solved it by figuring out $p^2$ order subgroup has p+1 $p$ order cyclic groups. and then calculating number of ways p+1 cyclic group combination, and taking care of double counting.